# How should I interpret the following notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I've come across this unfamiliar notation, and I have no clue how to interpret it. Can anyone help?

[image]

Specifically, I do not know how to interpret $b:b_i=1$ where $b$ is a sequence such that $b = (b_1, b_2,\dots,b_s)$ and each $b_i$ is equal to either $+1$ or $-1$.

Comment: It will be necessary to know what $B$ is, so that we can understand how to interpret $B^b$ where $b$ is an $s$-tuple of the kind you describe.  The rest of the notation seems fairly clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of set builder notation, at last check. It means "such that" like in $\{x:x^2 \text{ is odd}\}$